# Database is not uploading after adding Session in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my website project, I made a register and login form, then I connected it to a database. The insertion was working. Now I added session to store the data of registration, but no data is getting inserted.  In addition to this, I am not getting any change in codes too, where I made change if there is a session. Once it said that localhost refused to connect, but now the browser is not giving any error like that. Can anyone please help me figure out where the problem in my code is?

My C# code is:

```
 protected void userRegister(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Khulna_website"].ConnectionString;
     string encoded_pass = encrypt_pass(Regi_Password.Text);
     using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))         
     {
         string insertQuery = "insert into dbo.users(user_f_name,user_l_name,user_password,user_email,user_age, user_gender) values (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Regi_Password, @Regi_Email, @Age, @Gender);";
         SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
         connection.Open();
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Password", encoded_pass);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Email", Regi_Email.Text);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age.Text);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.SelectedValue);
         try
         {
             com.ExecuteNonQuery();
             com.CommandText = "Select * from dbo.users where email = " + Regi_Email.Text;
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             da.Fill(dt);
             Session["User"]=dt.Rows[0]["user_f_name"];
             Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
             loginlabel.Text="Welcome, "+Session["User"];
             connection.Close();
         }
         catch
         {
             Label1.Text = "Registration Error!";
         }
     }
```

The HTML is:

```
    <form runat="server" method="post">
    <div class="header">
    <img id="icon" src="Images/logo.png">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for people, place, locations">
            <input type="submit" id="search_button" value="">           
        </form>
        <span id= "login" runat="server" onclick="login();"><asp:Label ID="loginlabel" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
    </div>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Body" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>


        <div id="Sign_Up_Form" style="display: none">
            <form class="modal-content animate">           
            <div class="input">
                <div>
                    <div>Name</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="First_Name" runat="server" placeholder="First Name" style="height: 20px; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Last_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" style="height: 20px; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Email</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Regi_Email" runat="server" placeholder="Your email here"  style="height: 20px; width:90%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Password</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Regi_Password" type="password" runat="server" placeholder="**********" style="height: 20px;  width: 90%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Confirm Password</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Confirm_Regi_Password" type="password" runat="server" placeholder="**********" style="height: 20px;  width: 90%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Birth Date</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Age" type="number" runat="server" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" style="height: 20px;  width: 90%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Gender</div>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="radio" ID="Gender" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem CssClass="radio" Value="1">Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem CssClass="radio" Value="2">Female</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem CssClass="radio" Value="3">Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </br>
                </div>
           </div>
           <asp:Button ID="Register_Button" runat="server" value="Join" OnClick="userRegister" CssClass="button_join" Text="Join" />
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
           </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is you are using the same SqlCommand that you have with the "insert" command to fill the data adapter (you don't change the command).

You can solve this three ways:

First one: Change the SqlCommand to a SELECT clause with the information you need to fill your session just before creating the DataAdapter.

Second one: Just fill your session with the form data like:

```
Session["user"] = Regi_Email.Text;
Session["user_name"] = First_Name.Text;
```

Of course you should handle the errors if the insert fails.

Third One: Use stored procedure so you can insert and fill the data adapter with a select in the same query.

IMHO i would prefer option 2 or 3.

Also i think you have to consider to have a better exception handling (Not all the errors that can actually happen are because the email is already in use) and you should consider using the "using" statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for disposing/closing the objects (SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is data is not getting updated anymore, since the data is not updated, so adding session is not working also. I used SQLConnection in public class, and the command in protected class, so couldn't use using().. Is there any other alternative here?

Comment: You said insertion was working before adding Session. Did you add the SqlDataAdapter part when you added the Session too? Try removing the SqlDataAdapter part and use the option 2 i suggested, is insertion still not working?

Comment: no, it's not. Even I tried to go back to the initial code where it worked, but now it's not working anymore.

Comment: Mm.. That's weird. My guess is that the problem is out of the scope of this post (Maybe in the sql connection or the database?).

Comment: I have changed my code, now database is uploading.. but the session is not creating... I am editing the code in the original post... the change of the catch block is displaying, no change is shown in session..